No named parameter with the name 'flipRightIconIfOpen'. flipRightIconIfOpen: true,
This is how I called the flipRightIconOpen;
headerPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
flipRightIconIfOpen: true,
headerBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
contentBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
header: Text(
    storeDataContoller
            .storeDataInfo?.faQdata[j].question ??

I've increased the package in pubspec to   accordion: ^2.6.0 but still

Does using isOpen work for you?

It gives me this The named parameter 'flipRightIconIsOpen' isn't defined

headerPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
flipRightIconIfOpen: true,
headerBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
contentBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
header: Text(
storeDataContoller
.storeDataInfo?.faQdata[j].question ??
"",

can you share the widget name, cant find flipRightIconIfOpen on their repo. I was referring  isOpen: true  instead

isOpen:  true worked

widget is accordion
